# Form submit cancels jQuery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, forms, generic-handler

I have a Generic Handler (DownloadHandler.cs) which serves as both generating a pdf and downloading a pdf. When generating I use a jQuery ajax call and when downloading I use a form element which is submitted.  The problem is that the form element cancels the generate request and therefore the "success" event never gets called (See image below).

[image: Status List]

Generate code (Gets called from a button):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DownloadHandler.ashx",
    data: {
        GeneratePdf: true
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Download code (Gets called from a button):

```
var data = { "GeneratePdf": false }

var inputs = '';

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    inputs += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + value + '" />';
});

$('<form action="/DownloadHandler.ashx" method="POST">' + inputs + '</form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

DownloadHandler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["GeneratePdf"]) && Convert.ToBoolean(context.Request["GeneratePdf"]))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Write("GENERATING");
        context.Response.Flush();
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        FileInfo pdfFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\1.pdf");

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFile.Name);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfFile.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.WriteFile(pdfFile.FullName);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I just added a Thread.Sleep to demonstrate the generation of the pdf. Am I missing something or should I use some other method?

Comment: Submitting a form does reload a page, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but when you return a file with an "attachment" header it just downloads it instead of reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try targetting a tiny dynamic `iframe` on your page with your form. Something like :

```
var data = { "GeneratePdf": false }

var inputs = '';

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    inputs += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + value + '" />';
});

var f = $('<form action="/DownloadHandler.ashx" method="POST">' + inputs + '</form>');


var iframe = $('<iframe src="about:blank"/>')  // should be made tiny/transparent with some css
              .appendTo('body');

iframe.contents().find('html').append(f);
f.submit().remove();
```

Comment: That canceled both the DownloadHandler.ashx and the _blank iframe :( It seems when i'm submitting a form everything on a page gets canceled. I'm thinking of using another way of downloading the pdf since this seems to be the problem

Comment: @Dumpen modified my answer to put the form inside the iframe. I guess a possible answer should be something like this. Hope this will help.

Comment: It works in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. Do you know why? EDIT: Funny thing, my original post works in IE but not in Chrome >.>

Comment: @Dumpen Do you get any error message ? Random thought : it could be an issue with src about:blank of the iframe. Have you tried pointing to a valid html file (with a blank body) as src ?